# Fixing duplicate rows to adhere to constraint

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to force existing rows to be unique on a column before adding a unique constraint? I am adding this constraint to my db:

```
create unique index customfields_name_org_id_key 
on CustomFields(name, org_id) where deleted is false;
```

But would like to first find all cases where this constraint wouldn't be met, and add 1 to the name of one of the rows (adding higher numbers if there are more than 2 colliding rows). So, for example,

```
SELECT name, org_id, deleted,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name, deleted ORDER BY org_id) AS rnum
FROM customfields ORDER BY org_id;
```

gives me

```
   name    | org_id | deleted | rnum 
-----------+--------+---------+------
 Another   |      1 | f       |    1
 Bad email |      1 | t       |    1
 Dog?      |      1 | f       |    1
 New       |      1 | f       |    1
 New       |      1 | f       |    2
 New       |      1 | t       |    1
 New field |      1 | t       |    1
```

and I would like

```
 New       |      1 | f       |    2
```

To be renamed "New2"

I have written this code:

```
update CustomFields
  set name  = case
         when cf.rnum = 1 or cf.deleted
         then cf.name
         else cf.name || rnum
      end
  from (SELECT name, org_id, deleted,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name, deleted ORDER BY org_id) AS rnum
FROM customfields ORDER BY org_id) as cf;
```

But it just takes the first row from the select and renames all the names to "Another". How do I alter this code so that the update works on the corresponding rows in cf?

Sample code: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=iKSKze0tGm

Comment: Please post https://dbfiddle.uk code with sample data.

Comment: Added that to the end of my post. Thank you! Useful site to know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update table by using:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name, deleted ORDER BY org_id) AS rnum
   FROM customfields
)
UPDATE CustomFields 
SET name  = (SELECT case when cf.rnum = 1 or cf.deleted then cf.name
                    else cf.name || rnum end
             FROM cte cf WHERE cf.id = CustomFields.id);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=753b1756cccbb2ecc97d74daea127ace)**

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!